# Is it possible to simplify small if statements in python?

Tags: python

I have a program that adjusts some values when an input is negative.
Those values cannot be grouped for various reasons (I cannot put them all into one nice if statement).

This is a code example:

```
if num > 0:
    n_op = 50
else:
    n_op = -50
```

OR

```
n_op = 50
if num < 0:
    n_op = -50 (OR) n_op= -n_op
```

Pieces like this happen everywhere in my code and I am starting to get sick of it. Not only it doesn't seem like the most efficient solution, they also make the code look like crap.

Is there a way to make those specific pieces of code nicer?

Comment: *they also make the code look like crap*. No they don't.

Comment: `n_op = 50 if num > 0 else -50`.

Comment: No need to downvote. I don't know python well and I surely won't search for "Ternary conditional operator" randomly by not knowing the term. I would have searched already if I knew it.

Comment: Another alternative: `import numpy as np; n_op = 50 * np.sign(num)`

Comment: @jeremysprofile: not sure if this requires the quite hefty numpy hammer though.

Comment: Another alternative: `import math; n_op = int(math.copysign(num, 50))`

Comment: @user9549355: please don't assume that those that comment are the same people that voted. All that'll happen is that people will stop commenting on your posts, depriving you of feedback. No one here has implied you should have know to search for ternary conditional operator.